# Fair Odds Rule Clarification

Tags: probability, statistics

> Fair Odds Rule: In a fair bet, payoff odds = chance odds
>
> i.e.
>
> Chance odds: $18$ to $20$ ($18$ outcomes to win, $20$ outcomtes to lose) $= 18/38$
>
> Accoring to the rule, payout odds should also be: $18$ to $20?? = 18/20$ to $1$ so for every $\$1$ you bet, you'll get $\$1 + \$0.9$ back if you win?

How does this rule even work? Shouldn't payoff odds be the inverse of chance odds?

If I won by $1\%$ chance, I sure hope to get rewarded more than $1\%$ of my bet!

Comment: You have the right idea.  I think you need to defin payoff odds.

Comment: Rather than phrasing things in terms of odds, I find it much easier to work with things phrased in terms of probabilities.  Supposing we are playing a game where we either win or lose, we win with probability $p$, and lose with probability $q=1-p$, we pay an amount $k$ to play which we lose if we don't win and we get back an amount $k+w$ if we win.  Let $X$ be the random variable for the result of the game.  We want $E[X]=0$.  We have $E[X]=-k\cdot q + (k+w)\cdot p = 0$.  In the event $k=1$ that would be $0=-(1-p)+(1+w)p$, which you can solve for $w$ in terms of $p$.

Comment: Part of your difficulty might be that the phrase "odds" is ambiguous whether we are talking about the odds *for* winning or the odds *against* winning (*which is a large part of why I dislike working with odds rather than probability*).  I expect that whatever notes you are following will be clearer once you realize this and clarify which odds you are referring to.